# Use spacebar to check and uncheck checkboxes in KDE

Tags: keyboard, linux-mint, kde, user-interface, kde-4

A powerful and necessary keyboard navigation element is the ability to use space bar to check / uncheck checkboxes. How to enable such behaviour for spacebar key in KDE 4.x ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is already there; you may need to give focus to the proper window/tab/form with the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key first, though.